# cflags reference for writing makefiles

Tags: makefile

```
GNU Make 3.82
```

Hello,

Is there any reference materials for finding the description of CFLAGS. I am editing someones makefile and I have this CFLAGS options. However, I just want to find a description of these to find out what they do.

```
sample: -Isrc -rdynamic, etc
```

Can anyone link me to any websites or online manuals?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: CFLAGS holds the C compiler flags so what goes in there depends on which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are passed to the compiler so you need to check the documentation for the specific compiler. However it looks like you are using GCC so the following may be helpful:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC

In this particular case -I is covered under directory options and -rdynamic is covered under link options.